# MSVC fail to upcast unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code fails on MSVC11 with the error

```
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::unique_ptr<DerivedClass>' to 'std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>'
```

The code:

```
class BaseClass
{ };

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{ };

void MyFunction(std::unique_ptr<BaseClass> obj)
{ };

int main()
{
      auto ptr = std::unique_ptr<DerivedClass>(new DerivedClass);
      MyFunction(ptr);                 // fails, with error about cannot convert type
      // MyFunction(std::move(ptr));   // This will work
}
```

As pointed out in the answers the reason is `std::move` is missing, but the error message confused me enough to post the question, so I've updated it so anyone who is similarly confused has the best chance of finding the answer.

Comment: I'd have thought this question isn't so terrible, given the confusing error message MSVC prints. As @DeadMG commented I'm not the only one caught out by this. Now, this Q&A will come up for anyone who searches for the compiler error...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your error has nothing to do with up or down casting. You are attempting to copy `ptr`, which is not allowed. If you pass `std::move(ptr)`, the cast will be implicit and automatic, like a regular pointer.

Comment: gah - this is why i shouldn't code at night. Although the error is the once i posted, which is not the usual error for failing to `move` a `unique_ptr`. I'm voting to close as not real question, since it's based on a mistake and the title and content aren't going to help anyone searching later, but thanks for your response, probably saved me an hour of fustration.

Comment: I wouldn't. This is like, the fifth time I've answered exactly this problem. Obviously needs more search body.

Comment: Fair enough, question is updated to try and catch people in similar situation.